# c# - httpwebrequest status code returns 200 instead of 404

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-response-codes

I'm trying this code..

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.goo4le.com/");
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
  Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);
}
```

goo4le is a non existing domain. So its supposed to return 404. Instead it returns 200 status.

I think its because of my broadband provider using a custom 404 page.

[This is what i see](http://airtelforum.com/main?InterceptSource=0&FailureMode=1&FailedURI=http://goo4le.com/&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=3) when i enter goo4le.com in my browser.

Can someone tell me how to get the real http status instead of my browser status?

Comment: I get an exception "The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.goo4le.com'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't get any status code when running this, I get a DNS error saying I cant lookup the domain.

I imagine you are exactly right about the ISP, they may be doing this via a DNS redirection given you dont get this error. You could solve this by using a DNS server other than the one your ISP provides, try googles 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 (https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

This from their FAQs

> **How is Google Public DNS different from my ISP's DNS service or other
>   open DNS resolvers? How can I tell if it is better?**
>
> Open resolvers and
>   your ISP all offer DNS resolution services. We invite you to try
>   Google Public DNS as your primary or secondary DNS resolver along with
>   any other alternate DNS services. There are many things to consider
>   when identifying a DNS resolver that works for you, such as speed,
>   reliability, security, and validity of responses. Unlike Google Public
>   DNS, some ISPs and open resolvers block, filter, or redirect DNS
>   responses.
>
> **How does Google Public DNS handle non-existent domains?**
>
> If
>   you issue a query for a domain name that does not exist, Google Public
>   DNS always returns an NXDOMAIN record, as per the DNS protocol
>   standards. The browser should show this response as a DNS error. If,
>   instead, you receive any response other than an error message (for
>   example, you are redirected to another page), this could be the result
>   of the following: A client-side application such as a browser plug-in
>   is displaying an alternate page for a non-existent domain. Some ISPs
>   may intercept and replace all NXDOMAIN responses with responses that
>   lead to their own servers. If you are concerned that your ISP is
>   intercepting Google Public DNS requests or responses, you should
>   contact your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable redirecting, unfortunatelly i can't test it, since i got another provider (if that's the problem).

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.goo4le.com/");
request.Method = "HEAD";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
  Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);
}
```

if it is working, it will most likely throw an exception, since everything that returns a statuscode that's not 200 throws one......
if you wanna catch it try this:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.goo4le.com/");
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
  Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);
}

}
catch (WebException e)
{
   // in this case it was a status code exception (not status 200...)
   if (e.Response != null) Console.Write((int)e.Response.StatusCode);
   else throw;
}
```